# Pybind error: dll export implies default visibility, but class pybind11... has already been declared with a different visibility

Tags: python, c++, dll, pybind11

I am trying to bind some C++ code with Python using Pybind11 and I am getting this error

```
"dll export implies default visibility, but class pybind11... has already been declared with a different visibility"
```

(check image in the link below)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FE6k.png]

In Linux it compiles and runs without any issue. However, in Windows it fails to compile with this issue.

Here my Makefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(dico)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


#find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)

pybind11_add_module(read_dico main.cpp)
```

Main.cpp it is a C++ code to read a DLL and I want to be able to interface it with python. Anyone has any idea why I am having this error ?

Thank you in advance,

Fred

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve] and provide that here, along with how you (try to) compile it. BTW: The above Makefile is not actually one but one aimed at cmake. Since even that is just a tool to run the compiler, it should be stripped as well, unless absolutely necessary to demo the problem.